# Aplicación Java sobre oc4j: partes funcionan como programa pero fallan si se ejecuta como servicio

Tags: java, linux

Estoy manteniendo una aplicación bastante antigua basada en java 1.4 y el contenedor oc4j sobre linux. Aparte de los problemas derivados de su antigüedad, me he topado con uno al que no le encuentro explicación. Si ejecuto el jar del contenedor manualmente con `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0/jre/bin/java -jar oc4j.jar` toda la aplicación funciona correctamente, cada una de sus partes. Sin embargo si lo ejecuto como servicio `sudo systemctl start oc4j.service` hay partes que fallan. La que me está dando quebraderos de cabeza arroja este fallo:

```
ERROR:        Error code:<> es.gtd.coga.portal.entitylist.ScrollableList.DoStartTag() error  
Error message: Attribute [embdTicketsList] not found
```

Entiendo que este error es de poca ayuda dado que es propio de la aplicación, pero no hay absolutamente nada en los logs. Se produce de manera inmediata al realizar una función (generar y publicar un informe), cosa que ejecutando la aplicación manualmente no pasa. Si alguien sabe qué puede estar pasando me sería de mucha ayuda.

Comment: El fallo ocurre en el código de la aplicación, no del contenedor... deberías añadir el código a la pregunta. Te aconsejo completar el [tour] para entender por qué la pregunta tal como está no se considera bien planteada

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Efectivamente, como dices, el fallo ocurre en el código de la aplicación, sin embargo parece estar sujeto a la manera en que se ejecute el contenedor, y eso es lo que me lleva loco. Sé que debería haber añadido código, la razón por la que no lo he hecho es por la extensión que puede tener. Intentaré agregarlo de todas maneras de la manera más precisa que pueda.